# Scrollbar not working in Mozzila and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I've made a custom scrollbar to scroll inside my accordion. I know that there are some issues with the scrollbar in some browsers. I don't care about the scrollbar style I just need to get it working (scroll with it).

Here is the fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/8nkpx9f6/11/

Here is a part of CSS code:

```
.popup .content {
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

My code works perfectly in Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set the height in this class, I'm stupid.

```
.popup .content {
  max-height: 90%;
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right:30px;
  height:something
}
```

Now If someone knows how to style the scrollbar in moz and safari, that would be cool

Comment: your max-height will work if you remove display: table; from the class .popup

Answer (score 0):

```
.popup {
position: relative;
margin: 20 auto;
padding: 5px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 95%;
position: relative;
transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
height: 280px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/*display: table;*/
margin-top: 10px;}
```